# How to get two different search forms in Magento one fulltext and one title search?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, search, catalogsearch, advanced-search

I want to do two different search types in two different search forms.

I got the head search in fulltext and i created a quicksearch.phtml to edit this as a title only search.

Is there a way to set the "title only search" settings in my quicksearch.phtml or the form.mini.phtml?

Code of quicksearch.phtml:

```
<?php
/* @var $this Mage_Core_Block_Template */
/* @var $catalogSearchHelper Mage_Catalogsearch_Helper_Data */
$catalogSearchHelper =  $this->helper('catalogsearch');
?>
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="input-text form-control" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Search')) ?>" class="btn btn-default"></button>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape($this->__('Suchbegriff eingeben...')) ?>');
            searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

by the way i got Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: i know, that the settings are normaly made in the backend/admin panel but this have to be a different search on the same site.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple solution:** Point your "title only" search form to `Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result')` and change the name of the search input field to `name="name"` (or `name="meta_title` or whatever you use as "title" attribute).

Drawback: You will lose the autocomplete feature. To not see errors or wrong results, remove the "search_autocomplete" div and the following script.